# Run two processes in parallel one on adb and another on windows using cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, adb

I want to run two programs one on adb and another on windows. But it should be done parallely and compare outputs of two.

I can use cygwin to do this sequencially:

for adb :

```
adb shell ./program1 > out1.txt
```

for windows :

```
./program2.exe >out2.txt
```

and then diff  `out1.txt out2.txt`

run.sh file:

```
adb shell ./program1 > out1.txt
./program2.exe >out2.txt
out1.txt out2.txt
```

Above approach runs program on adb first , then on windows (Sequencially)

I want both programs to run in parallel and `diff` when both complete.

I need the approach to put one process in background as in linux :

```
(adb shell ./program1 > out1.txt)  & (./program2.exe >out2.txt)
```

Is there any way to do this using CygWin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `cygwin` but I guess something like this:

```
adb shell ./program1 > out1.txt &
./program2.exe >out2.txt &
wait
diff ...
```

I assume you are using a `bash` shell.